# Drop-down menu with multiple columns with PHP and MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, select

I need a drop down menu with multiple columns. The data in options is coming from MySQL using PHP. Here is my code

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM accounts");

    <select class="form-dropdown validate[required]" style="width:515px;" id="accountTitleOptions" name="accountTitle-options">
            <option selected value="--- Select Option ---"> --- Select Option --- </option>
            <?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) { ?>
            <option><?php echo $row['accountTitle'] ?> <?php echo $row['accountNumber'] ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
    </select>
```

This is how my codes output looks like:

```
Karachi Traders 692700001
Zulfiqar Ahmad 692700002
Mian Sarfaraz 692700003
Malik Younus Commission Shop 692700004
Farhan Ashraf Commission Shop 692700006
```

[My result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mt2iD.jpg).

But I what I want is properly organized dropdown like this

```
Karachi Traders                         692700001
Zulfiqar Ahmad                          692700002
Mian Sarfaraz                           692700003
Malik Younus Commission Shop            692700004
Farhan Ashraf Commission Shop           692700006
```

I have tried many solutions but still nothing have given me desired output.

Comment: I think you should try using html and css can help display in a proper way

Answer (score 0):

An approach (a plain-text approach):

- use a [monospaced font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font)
- count the number of characters for each item
- concatenate a number of spaces with each item, which equals (max_no_of_chars - no_of_chars)
- then concatenate your number

hope it helps