# PHP dropdown with multiple columns alignment

Tags: php, alignment, multiple-columns, dropdown

I require a HTML dropdown menu with 3 columns (obtained from PHP variables), which are nicely aligned.
I have managed to add whitespace using the code below:

```
<select id = transfer_box name="transfers" size="20">  
<?php
while ($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc())
{
  $player_name = $rows ['full_name'];
  $price = $rows ['initial_value'];
  $price_formatted = '£'.$price.'m';
  $detailed_position = $rows ['detailed_position'];
  echo "<option value='$player_name'> $player_name &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; $price_formatted &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; $detailed_position </option>";    
}
?>
```

I have also tried combining the three varaibles into one string. I can add whitespace, but not align.

I am seeking the same result as shown in the below question, which was never really answered. Can anyone help?

[Drop-down menu with multiple columns with PHP and MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41523557/drop-down-menu-with-multiple-columns-with-php-and-mysql)

Comment: _Small Point_ PHP does not have dropdowns. But the good news is HTML does

Comment: Are you using a mono-space font?

Comment: Didnt the question/Answer you link to give you all the clues you need?

Comment: Fair point. I'm using PHP to obtain the dropdown options from a MySQL database, but you're right, the dropdown will be a HTML dropdown.

Comment: font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-size:14px;

Comment: I'll try the answer in the link. Just with zero votes I thought it probably wasn't good.

Comment: Basically it is not a totally trivial process, so whoever answered the other question was not going to spend an hour or so writing and testing a full answer. But the logic seems sensible

Comment: Thanks. I agree the logic seems sensible. It will involve a bit more work and learning, but I'll pursue it.

Comment: Once you have made a decent attempt and have code, it is more likely that you will get useful help form here. Currently the question looks a bit "Do it for me" Good luck

Comment: The method outlined as an answer in the original question works:  In MySQL create a column for the required maximum length minus char_length(first column), say 'result_column'  Then use repeat('&nbsp;','result_column'). This generates the number of required spaces in the HTML output.  The only problem is the monospace font gives a really unnappealing, dated aesthetic. I am going to seek an alternative, more aesthetic solution.